# Can't convert view.tag ObjC code to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm migrating some code to Swift and I stumbled upon this line that for some reason works with ObjC but not with Swift.

ObjC:

```
if (view.tag == 'C'+'L'+'O') {
```

And now what I wrote in Swift that isn't working:

```
if view.tag == "C" + "L" + "O" {
```

It says `Ambiguous reference to operator function '=='`

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: My general advice on this is to just pretend that tags don't exists. They were a design mistake IMO, as there are *so* many different, *much better* ways of identifying child views.

Comment: I will try to approach this differently then. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'C'`, `'L'`, and `'O'` in C-based languages are `char`s which are 8-bit signed (or unsigned) integers, so their values can be added and compared to an `Int`.

You were attempting to add `"C"`, `"L"`, and `"O"` which are `String`s so the result with string concatenation is the `String` `"CLO"`.  In Swift, you can't compare a `String` to an `Int`.  Admittedly, that would have been the better error message.

The equivalent in Swift would be:

```
if view.tag == UnicodeScalar("C").value + UnicodeScalar("L").value + UnicodeScalar("O").value {
```

That's really awful for a number of reasons including the fact that order doesn't matter so 'C' + 'L' + 'O' and 'O' + 'C' + 'L' yield the same result.   Better alternatives exist in Swift.  @EmilioPelaez gives some good alternatives in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59072798/1630618).

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

In C and ObjC characters (denoted with a single `'` quote, instead of double `"` quotes for strings) are actually ints, which is why you can add them together and assign them to `tag`, which is an int.

Swift does have a character type, but it's not an int, and in this case you are adding three strings, which will result in the string `"CLO"`, which can't be assigned to the `tag` property because the property is an int.

Personally I'm against using view's tags, I prefer creating a subclass and creating a new variable to store the relevant information.

However, if you want to keep using tags, you could use the hash value of the string, so `if view.tag == "CLO".hashValue`. This is not perfectly equivalent, since `"CLO".hashValue` will be different from `"COL".hashValue`, which won't be the case in ObjC. **NOTE:** As mentioned by @Alexander, the hash value will be different on each launch of the app. If you are persisting data between launches, don't use `hashValue`

A better alternative would be to create an int-backed enum and add their raw values.

An even better alternative would be to create an option set, make a subclass or `UIView` or whatever you're using, and add a property to store them there. Then you can check if the view has all the values you need.

Comment: `hashValue` wouldn't work either, because Swift's hashing algorithm is randomly seeded on program startup, to prevent hash-collision based DoS attacks. https://forums.swift.org/t/psa-the-stdlib-now-uses-randomly-seeded-hash-values/10789

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I didn't get the impression that they'd be persisting the value between launches, but I still added a note.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez If it was set programmatically on every app launch, that would work fine, but consider that the tag is likely set statically in an interface builder file.